# Django download csv from model database

Tags: python, django

I don't know why this is so difficult but I want to download a CSV file that has already been saved to my database for users to look at on their own PCs. Here are my models and views:

models.py

```
class datasheet(models.Model):
    file_name = models.FileField(upload_to = 'upload', max_length = 100)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'File id: {}'.format(self.id)
```

views.py

```
def download(request):
    csvfile = datasheet.objects.get(id = 1)
    return (csvfile as a downloaded attachment)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/files/#using-files-in-models)

```py
import os
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404

def download(request):
    csvfile = datasheet.objects.get(id = 1)
    if os.path.exists(csvfile.file_name.path):
        with open(csvfile.file_name.path, 'rb') as fh:
            response = HttpResponse(fh.read(), content_type="text/csv")
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=' + os.path.basename(csvfile.file_name.path)
            return response
    raise Http404
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add "download" attribute inside your tag to download files.

```
<a download href="{{ datasheet.file_name.url }}">{{ datasheet.file_name }}</a>
```

**Or** **[FileResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#fileresponse-objects)** is a subclass of `StreamingHttpResponse` optimized for binary files.

```
import os

from django.http import FileResponse

def download(request):
    csvfile = datasheet.objects.get(id=1)
    fullpath = csvfile.file_name.path
    if not os.path.exists(fullpath):
        raise Http404('{0} does not exist'.format(fullpath))

    return FileResponse(
        open(fullpath, 'rb'), as_attachment=True,
        filename=csvfile.file_name.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

nothing you need except, opening the file and returning it as an attachment file to the response object.

```py
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseNotFound


file_location = 'upload/'+csvfile

with open(file_location, 'r') as f:
   file_data = f.read()

# sending response 
response = HttpResponse(file_data, content_type='text/csv')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="{}"'.format(csvfile)

return response
```